# CodeIgniter Assets Directory String Helper

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter, helper

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.7 with url helper autoloaded and enabled.

How to code `assets_helper.php` that make use of `base_url();` to parse `https://something.tld/` and put the first group as the subfolder if there is no group then it will use the base assets folder?

From

```
<?php echo assets_url('css', 'style.css'); ?>
<?php echo assets_url('js', 'script.js'); ?>
<?php echo assets_url('php', 'test.php'); ?>
<?php echo assets_url('icon.ico'); ?>
```

To

```
https://something.tld/assets/css/style.css
https://something.tld/assets/js/script.js
https://something.tld/assets/php/test.php
https://something.tld/assets/icon.ico
```

I know it's easier to just write `<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>` to achieve this but it's hard to maintain let's say if I plan to change the assets folder to `/subfolder/1/2/3/assets/` next time. I could just change 1 variable in the helper file without messing with the original source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create  `asset_helper.php` then you need to autoload it. In codeigniter you can add new functions to the existing helper. Since `url_helper` is already autoloaded and ready to use , I will add new function to the url_helper.

Create a new File `MY_url_helper.php` in the `application/helpers` directory. 
Copy and paste the below code.

```
<?php
function assets_url($dir,$file=null){
    $assets_dir = base_url()."path/to/your/assets_folder/";
    $asset_path = $assets_dir.$dir;
    if(!empty($file)){
        $asset_path .="/$file";
    }
    return $asset_path;
}
```

Replace `path/to/your/assets_folder/` with your asset folder( ' / ' at the end is important).

Answer (score 0):

You may find this model I wrote useful it will need to be modified.

`$this->asset->load('item')`

If `item` is in the `$this->assets` array it will be loaded from there.
Otherwise you have to pass a url, or name: `$this->asset->load('item.js');`

You can also pass an array `$this->asset->load(array('item1.js', 'item2.css'));`

It will use the `link_tag` function from CI, and a custom `script_tag` function and return a string containing the appropriate js/css `<script>` and `<link>` tags.

Will require some modification and definition of constant `ASSET_DIR`, `ROOT`. But the functionality is there.

```
class Asset_loader_model extends CI_Model {

    private $types = array('css', 'js');
    private $assets = array();

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->assets = $this->n_config->get('plugin_assets');
    }

    /**
     * Loads an asset or assets by key
     * 
     * @param string $asset
     * @param boolean $return Default to false
     */
    public function load($asset, $return = false) {
        $out = '';
        if (is_array($asset)) {
            foreach ($asset as $src) {
                $out .= $this->load($src, true);
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($this->assets[$asset])) {
                // asset is in the plugins array
                $out .= $this->__load($this->assets[$asset]);
            } elseif (is_file(ROOT . ASSETS_DIR . $asset)) {
                // asset must be a /js/include.js
                $out .= $this->__load($asset);
            } else {
                trigger_error("Could not find asset {$asset}.", E_USER_WARNING);
            }
        }
        if ($return) {
            return $out;
        } else {
            echo $out;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads a single asset array by key
     * 
     * @param key $asset
     * @return string
     */
    private function __load($asset) {
        $out = '';
        if (is_array($asset)) {
            foreach ($asset as $type => $srcs) {
                if (!in_array($type, $this->types)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (is_array($srcs)) {
                    foreach ($srcs as $src) {
                        $out .= $this->load_individual($src, $type);
                    }
                } else {
                    $out .= $this->load_individual($srcs, $type);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $type = $this->get_type($asset);
            if (in_array($type, $this->types)) {
                $out .= $this->load_individual($asset, $type);
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Gets type based on extension
     * 
     * @param string $src
     * @return string $type
     */
    public function get_type($src) {
        return pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }

    /**
     * Outputs src in proper html tag
     * 
     * @param string $src
     * @param string $type
     */
    private function load_individual($src, $type) {
        if (!is_http($src)) {
            $src = base_url(ASSETS_DIR . $src);
        }
        switch ($type) {
            case 'js':
                return script_tag($src);
                break;
            case 'css':
                return link_tag($src);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Asset_helper:

```
if (!function_exists('script_tag')) {

    /**
     * Script
     *
     * Generates link to a JS file
     *
     * @param mixed $src Script source or an array
     * @param bool $index_page Should index_page be added to the js path
     * @return string
     */
    function script_tag($src = '', $index_page = false) {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $script = '<script ';
        if (is_array($src)) {
            foreach ($src as $k => $v) {
                if ($k === 'src' && !preg_match('#^([a-z]+:)?//#i', $v)) {
                    if ($index_page === true) {
                        $script .= 'src="' . $CI->config->site_url($v) . '"';
                    } else {
                        $script .= 'src="' . $CI->config->slash_item('base_url') . $v . '"';
                    }
                } else {
                    $script .= $k . '="' . $v . '" ';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (preg_match('#^([a-z]+:)?//#i', $src)) {
                $script .= 'src="' . $src . '"';
            } elseif ($index_page === true) {
                $script .= 'src="' . $CI->config->site_url($src) . '"';
            } else {
                $script .= 'src="' . $CI->config->slash_item('base_url') . $src . '"';
            }
        }
        return $script . ' type="text/javascript"' . "></script>";
        //return $script . '></script>'; // w3c no need for type
    }

}

/**
 * Checks if a string contains a url
 * 
 * @param string $str
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_http($str) {
    return preg_match("/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/", $str);
}
```